# What about stored procedures in MYSQL except quires in programming that we normally use? how much it will works efficiently

Tags: mysql

i am starting new Web app and thinking about stored procedures of mysql to create except manually query usage will they helpful in long terms mean in future? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure is a prepared SQL code that you can save, so the code can be reused over and over again.

So if you have an SQL query that you write over and over again, save it as a stored procedure, and then just call it to execute it.

You can also pass parameters to a stored procedure, so that the stored procedure can act based on the parameter value(s) that is passed.

you will get more details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_stored_procedures.asp)